# Using Reflection to set a Property with a type of List<CustomClass>

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-2.0

How can I use reflection to create a generic List with a custom class (List<CustomClass>)?  I need to be able to add values and use
`propertyInfo.SetValue(..., ..., ...)` to store it.  Would I be better off storing these List<>'s as some other data structure?

Edit:

I should have specified that the object is more like this, but Marc Gravell's answer works still.

```
class Foo
{
    public List<string> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is string really a custom class? I was hoping you'd be talking about something like using reflection to invoke a class MyClass that has a property that is a List<SomeOtherClass> where SomeOtherClass is a class I made that has a bunch of properties and constructors etc...

Comment: Ok, so string was a bad choice for a class, but it sufficed as an explanation.  One can replace string with just about any class so far as my limited knowledge goes, but in the case I was asking for, the class and the type in the list are found by reflection only.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Type type = typeof(Foo); // possibly from a string
        IList list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));

        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        type.GetProperty("Bar").SetValue(obj, "abc", null);
        list.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i have

class Foo{
     public List<Bar> bars {get; set;}
}

class Bar{
public byte Id { get; set; }
public byte Status { get; set; }
public byte Type { get; set; }
public Bar(){}
}

I instantiate foo using reflection, activator.createinstance(). Now I need to populate that list of bars with Bar objects.

Comment: should the code you have there compile? I'm told that I still need to supply the declaration of the IList with a type... 
IList<typeof(type)> or something, I don't know?

Comment: I can do  
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(GetListType(p.ParameterType)));

But I don't seem to get a list in return since list doesn't seem to have an Add method...

Comment: missing using system.collection;

Comment: For brevity, it isn't uncommon to omit the `using` declarations.

Comment: The question is about setting an indexed propertly (hence List<string>) . The answer is for a string property. This answer is confusing because setting a single object property and setting indexed properties seem to be different.

Comment: @detay fair enough; however, I would advise using the non-generic IList in that case

Comment: Nice, but missing an explanation on how to achieve setting nested Lists. For example MyObject.MyList[0].SecondList[1].SomeValue

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of taking the List<> type and turning it into List<string>.

var list = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string));

Comment: That doesn't give you a list of any kind - it gives you a Type