# How to figure out if a Property is a List<T> where T is of custom Type?

Tags: c#, reflection

I've got two models

```
public class Foo{
    public List<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class Bar{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Then I have another method that looks something like this.

```
DoStuff<Foo, Bar>();
```

```
public void DoStuff<TModel, TCollection>(){

    foreach(var property in typeof(TModel).GetProperties())
    {
        if ( property.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(TCollection) )
        {
            // this is the property we need...
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is not working. How do I figure out if the property within the Model is a List of TCollection?

Comment: "The above code is not working." Use the debugger to look at runtime behavior and values.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1312311/69809) should get you closer to your solution.

Comment: Instead of using reflection you should add method parameter: `Func<TModel, List<TCollection>>` and use it like that: `DoStuff<Foo, Bar>(f => f.Bars)`.

Comment: In the `DoStuff` method implementation you seem to be referencing some `model` variable which is unclear where is it coming from. This might explain why your code is not working. Normally you should use variables that are in scope.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov sorry, I omitted some code that pertains to what you're referring to. I've updated.

Comment: You should absolutely **not** be calling `property.GetType()` - you probably want `property.PropertyType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what scenarios you want to cater for. At the most basic, you could check for `IsGenericType` and `GetGenericTypeDefinition()==typeof(List<>)`. However! That fails a few cases, in particular custom subclasses, etc. The approach that much of the BCL takes is "is it an `IList` (non-generic) and does it have a non-`object` indexer?"; i.e.

```
static Type GetListType(Type type)
{
    if (type == null) return null;

    if (!typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(type)) return null;

    var indexer = type.GetProperty("Item", new[] { typeof(int) });
    if (indexer == null || indexer.PropertyType == typeof(object)) return null;

    return indexer.PropertyType;
}
```

with:

```
public void DoStuff<TModel, TCollection>()
{
    foreach (var property in typeof(TModel).GetProperties())
    {
        var itemType = GetListType(property.PropertyType);
        if(itemType == typeof(TCollection))
        {
            // this is the property we need
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your `var indexer = type.GetProperty( "Item", new[] { typeof( int ) } );` line is broken. I'm not seeing what you're doing there with the `typeof(int)`.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell no, it is not broken - it is looking for an indexer of the form `public SomeType this[int index] {...}` - the `new[]{typeof(int)}` is the *indexer signature* (and `Item` is the name that the CLI uses for an indexer)

Comment: Cannot resolve the method 'GetProperty(string, System.Type[])'.. looks like it doesn't like the array.

Comment: @Chase it has [been there since 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efekk662(v=vs.80).aspx) - are you perhaps using an unusual framework? CF? MF? SL?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell see, that's the kind of detail that would really help ;p Not to worry - it just makes it a bit less convenient - just use `GetProperty("Item")` perhaps - if you were being *strict*, you could also check the indexer signature manually, but - meh, it'll be fine without it usually.

Comment: nice, I'll give it a try... sorry about the missing detail.

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this help?

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof (Foo).GetProperties())
{
    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    {
        var isAList = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (List<>);
        var isGenericOfTypeBar = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(Bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `Foo` and `Bar` are completely hidden from the `DoSomething<TModel, TCollection>()` method.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell that's fine - just replace `Foo` with `TModel` and `Bar` with `TCollection` throughout

Comment: @Lawrence not that this fails for a large number of implementations, including `public class BarList : List<Bar> {}` - works great for `List<Bar>` by itself, though

Comment: @MarkGravell.  I realise that this fails for objects that aren't exactly `List<Bar>`.  As you comment on your question - it depends exactly what @ChaseFlorrell means by "List". I like your `GetListType()` method - I would mark this as the answer...